# Why is CoreData not saved when I reopen the app in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I am having a problem involving CoreData and terminating the app. When I terminate the app (even if I do save the Managed Object Context,) and reopen it, It still looks the same for some reason. . .

I'm a bit new to CoreData, but is there a way to update data maybe? I'l also Share pics of the app for reference and the code down bellow:

```
List{
   ForEach(tasks, id: \.id){ task in CellView(completionState: task.completionState, title: task.title!,
 priority: task.priority ?? "")

}
```

This code is used in the UI to display the data, and it works, then we have the CellView struct

```
struct CellView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
    
    @State  var completionState: Bool
    @State  var title: String
    @State  var priority: String
    @State  var actionSheetPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            //Mark task complete//
            Button(action: {
                completionState.toggle()
                do {
                        try self.moc.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    }
            }) {
                switch completionState{
                case false:
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                        .resizable()
                    
                    
                case true:
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
                        .resizable()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                    
                }
                
            }
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            
            Spacer()
            
            switch priority {
            case "Dorment":
                
                Button(action: {self.actionSheetPresented.toggle()}) {
                    Image(systemName: "zzz")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .padding(.trailing, 10.0)
                
                
                
            default:
                Button(action: {self.actionSheetPresented.toggle()}) {
                    
                    Text(priority)
                        .background(Image("buttonBackground")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                                        .cornerRadius(30.0))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .padding(.trailing)
                
            }
            
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $actionSheetPresented, content: {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("Change the priority"), message: nil, buttons: [
                .default(Text("A")) {
                    priority = "A"
                    
                    do {
                        try self.moc.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    }
                },
                .default(Text("B")) {
                    priority = "B"
                    
                    do {
                        try self.moc.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    }
                },
                .default(Text("C")) {
                    priority = "C"
                    
                    do {
                        try self.moc.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    }
                },
                .default(Text("Dorment")) {
                    priority = "Dorment"
                    do {
                        try self.moc.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    }},
                .cancel()
            ])
        })
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
    }
}
```

Yes. . .I am aware some of these saves aren't right. . . but I really don't know how to make it work.

I also have some pictures you can use to understand what I mean:

This is the first picture, mostly the initial state:

[image]

And this is the state it should remain once I reopen the app. . .but It doesn't:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you have set up the data to be saved. While you don't list your Core Data model, I will assume that the Entity is `Task` and the Attributes are `title`, `priority` and `completionState`. Therefore, you to save the data, you need to define a variable in the managed object context to hold the data, add the data to the variable, and then save the data in the context:

```
let task = Task(context: self.moc)
task.title = self.title
task.priority = self.priority
task.completionState = self.completionState

do {
    try self.moc.save()
} catch {
    // catch any errors here  
}
```

All you have done is told the context to save the data that already exists in there without changing it in any way. I would also pull this pattern out into a function that you can call, rather than having it in each section of the action sheet.

Comment: Alright, I will let you know how it turns out!